# Проблема массовой рассылки в Телеграме

Tags: php, telegram-bot, запрос, limit

Реализовал бота, который каждые 5 минут парсит один сайт с объявлениями и оповещает пользователей по категориям (0-5 оповещений за один раз).

Все работает хорошо, но вот лимит телеграма в 30 сообщений/секунду всему мешает. Пользователей может быть очень много, а при идеальных обстоятельствах получится отправить только 9000 сообщений за 5 минут. Этого в будущем будет недостаточно.  И это еще не учитывая, что пользователи будут вести чат с ботом (настраивать его)

Перебирал разные варианты, вплоть до создания нескольких одинаковых ботов и разделения пользователей по ним. Но это не удобно, поэтому пишу сюда. Какие у вас есть идеи? Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Насколько я вижу вам нужно оптимизировать логику работы скрипта. Лимит в 30 сообщений/секунда вы никак не обойдете.

**Краткая выжимка из дальнейшего текста**

- Объединяйте несколько уведомлений в одно сообщение, это сократит
  нагрузку на лимиты в разы.
- Сегментируйте пользователей и тратьте лимиты на тех, кто в них
  реально нуждается (таких пользователей всегда будет меньшинство),
  остальным шлите общие отчеты.
- Запускайте скрипты условным "потоком", а не интервально раз в 5
  минут.
- Формируйте очереди на отправку и обрабатывайте их в зависимости от важности.
- Искусственно снижайте нагрузку, вводя плату за "мгновенные" уведомления.
- Оптимизируйте код для максимальной скорости работы скриптов и минимальных нагрузок

**Сегментация пользователей**

Для начала я бы рекомендовал вам делить пользователей на активных и пассивных. Положим у вашего бота миллион подписчиков. Их них в лучшем случае 100 000 будут активно проверять объявления в течение дня. Т.е. всех активных пользователей вы сможете перебрать за час (1800 в минуту * 60 = 98 000 пользователей).

Остальным можно отправлять общую сводку раз в сутки в разное время. (900 000 отправок = 10 часов работы, которые будут равномерно распределены в неактивные часы дня).

**Запуск скриптов "потоком"**

Я бы рекомендовал отойти от идеи парсинга раз в 5 минут и дальнейшего оповещения пользователей к постоянной работе с сайтом. Возможно вам потребуется приобрести proxy для захода на сайт с нескольких IP адресов, дабы не попасть под блокировку со стороны сисадмина сайта объявлений.

Попробуйте сделать массив категорий на сайте объявлений и их парсинг с задержкой в 10-15 секунд (зависит от скорости обработки парсером категории).

После этого сделайте отдельный парсинг категории. Допустим получится 6 категорий. Из этого следует что вам нужно настроить 6 CRON запусков каждую минуту со sleep параметром в n*10 секунд где n - номер скрипта(чтобы скрипты запускались не одновременно, а по очереди). Если категорий 12 - CRON на 2 минуты и т.д.

Точные значения подбирайте сами из нагрузки на ваш сервер.

**Очереди на отправку сообщений**

Во время парсинга формируйте очередь на отправку уведомлений пользователям. Затем эту очередь обрабатывайте уже непосредственно ботом.

Разделите очередь на новые уведомления и ответы на сообщения пользователей.
В первую очередь проверяйте нужно ли кому-то ответить и обрабатывайте в рамках лимита ответы пользователям, потом переходите к отправке новых сообщений.

Помещайте пользователей которым уже отправили сообщение в конец очереди на отправку сообщения.

**Объединяйте несколько уведомлений в одно сообщение**

Формируйте из нескольких объявлений для пользователя одно сообщение. Тогда не придется отправлять по 0-5 сообщений пользователю раз в 5 минут. Как я уже говорил неактивным пользователям можно отправлять шаблон общей сводки раз в сутки (мол по вашим категориям 10 новых объявлений, смотрите тут).

Для активных пользователей отправляйте сводку за час (при нагрузке в 100 000 активных пользователей, откуда берется эта цифра писал выше).

**Искусственно снижайте нагрузку вводя плату**

Можете сделать премиум-доступ, условно 5 000 человек, которые заплатили чтобы получать уведомления каждые 5 минут (5 000 / 1800 = 2,7 минуты на отправку всех сообщений).

**Доп проверки (на ранних этапах развития), увеличивает нагрузку**

Можете дополнительно настроить проверку сколько объектов уже в сообщении. Тогда например как только у пользователя скапливается 5 новых объектов - его сообщение отправляется вне очереди. (не рекомендую, увеличит нагрузку и пожрет лимиты).

**Оптимизируйте код**

Оптимизируйте код парсера/бота/запросы к БД. Тут сложно давать советы, т.к. не ясно с чем имеем дело, но пару общих принципов могу порекомендовать:

1. Попробуйте перед запуском парсера проверять изменения на странице
   через Last-Modified заголовок не загружая саму страницу. Это
   сократит нагрузку в разы. Подробнее:
   https://superuser.com/questions/619592/get-modification-time-of-remote-file-over-http-in-bash-script
   Причина, почему это может не сработать:
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644436/how-do-i-find-when-a-web-page-was-last-updated
2. Убивайте скрипт через die как только он перестает быть нужным. Не ждите завершения всего кода.
3. Один длинный запрос к БД как правило лучше чем несколько коротких.
4. Последние версии php работают быстрее древних.

Ну и оптимизируйте всю эту схему в зависимости от нагрузок.

**Итог**

В итоге получится что у вас постоянно формируется очередь отправки сообщений, причем сообщения постоянно дополняются объектами. В итоге к пользователю приходит новое уведомление не с четко заданным интервалом, а по мере работы скрипта.

Это не страшно т.к. пользователи не сидят всё время в телефоне и если уведомление о новом объекте придет на минуту позже - всё в порядке. Другая ситуация с ответами на команды пользователя - тут задержек быть не должно, поэтому очередь ответов должна обрабатываться первой. За лишнюю минуту задержки в отправке уведомления о новых объектах вы сможете обработать 1800 ответов пользователей.

Comment: Вау! Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ!

Comment: К сожалению, объденить несколько объявлений в одно сообщение нельзя, так как вместе с ним идет три кнопки (перейти на сайт, просмотреть информацию о заказчике и т.д)
С парсингом так же проблем нет, за 5 минут появляется не больше 5 объявлений, и я использую оф. АРІ. 
Общие отчеты - Это да, вариант хороший, но в телеграм боте невозможно отследить активность, разве что заставлять пользователя нажимать на кнопки. 
Оплата - да, это конечно будет, этот способ убивает 2 зайцев: Другие пользователи не ноют что приходит не сразу, и нагрузку снижает)